# Why do 'wonder' and 'think' act differently in wh-movement?

Tags: morphology, chomsky, movement, wh-words

### For instance:

Object moving:

1. Who do you think that John saw *t*? (correct)
2. *Who do you wonder that John saw *t*? (incorrect)

Subject moving:

1. Who do you think *t* saw John? (correct)
2. *Who do you wonder *t* saw John? (incorrect)

Adjunct moving:

1. Why do you think that I left *t*? (correct)
2. *Why do you wonder that I left *t*? (incorrect)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*Wonder* takes an embedded interrogative complement with its own internal *t*race:

> You wonder who John saw *t*.
>   You wonder who *t* saw John.
>   You wonder why I left *t*.

When you front that *wh-* you're asking it to do double duty, in both an  external interrogative and the embedded interrogative: in effect it's standing for itself rather than for the trace!

ADDED:
It's the interrogative role of the *wh-* complement which prohibits this movement. Note that this pair sustains the movement, because the original *wh-* clause is deployed not as an interrogative but as a pronominal:

> I know who saw John.  ⇒ <sup>ok</sup>Who do you know saw John?

But this pair doesn't, because the original *wh-* clause is interrogative:

> I'd like to know who saw John. ⇏ <sup>∗</sup>Who would you like to know saw John?

Some grammarians distinguish these two uses of the *wh-* clause as 'embedded questions' and 'free' or 'fused relatives'. I don't, because the internal structure of the *wh-* clause is identical; but the difference in the external syntactic roles justifies a distinction at that level.

Comment: Thank you! In addition, are there other verbs that also act like 'wonder'? Is there any way we can identify them?

Comment: In 'I wonder if she ate' , there doesn't seem to be an embedded interrogative complement but the phrase makes sense. Is there some logic to this exception? @StoneyB

Comment: @ToInfinityAndBeyond See my addition. The *if* in *I wonder if she ate* has the force of *whether*.